# HTML CSS - Keyframe animation causing weird issue on refresh

Tags: html, css, animation

Everything works fine up until I refresh the page. It seems the animation applies to the entire body when I refresh the page, including the `screen-splash`, `screen-loading` and `screen-main` divs. The more times I refresh, the more all the divs get distorted

When I comment out `animation: slide 4s linear infinite;` refreshing works fine

The function of the `main-screen-background` is to have a tiled background that's slowly moving towards the top-left infinitely (which works fine)

**HTML**

```
<div id="screen-splash" class="primary-screen hidden">
        <img src="img/logo.png"/ class="center noClick">
    </div>
    
    <div id="screen-loading" class="primary-screen hidden">
        <div id="screen-loading-loader-container" class="center noClick" style="text-align: center;color:black;">
            <span id="screen-loading-loader-container-loading">Loading</span>
            <span id="screen-loading-loader-container-percentage">0%</span><br>
            <span id="screen-loading-loader-container-url">/</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="screen-main" class="primary-screen hidden">
        <div id="screen-main-background">
        
        </div>
        <!-- many other divs with unique ids -->
        <div id="screen-main-..."> ... </div>
        <div id="screen-main-..."> ... </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#screen-main-background {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: url('../img/seamless-bg.png') repeat;
    background-size: 20vh;
    animation: slide 4s linear infinite;
    width: calc(100vw + 20vh);
    height: calc(100vh + 20vh);
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        top: -1vh;
        left: -1vh;
    }
}
```

***Loading Screen before refresh (properly centered)***

[image]

***Loading Screen after refresh (not properly centered anymore)***

[image]